# Axios network error even though the post request returns 200

Tags: react-native, axios

After enabling CORS and everything on my server, the error persists.

In other forms inside my app, uploading pictures works... but in this exact form, on iPhone it works absolutely fine, but on android after submitting, all I get is a "network error" although the post returns 200. I think this is an axios problem. **Only on android I get this issue.**

my code is the following:

```js
           const data = new FormData()
            data.append('subject_id', this.props.navigation.getParam('id'))
            data.append('name', this.state.title)
            data.append('progress', this.state.progress * 100)
            data.append('description', this.state.description)
            data.append('date', this.state.date)
            data.append('image', {
                uri: this.state.image,
                type: 'image/jpeg',
                name: 'image'
            });

            axios.post('https://example.com/api/auth/createTask', data, {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': access,
                    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
                },
            }).then(res => {
                this.props.navigation.navigate('ViewHW', { id: res.data.id })
            }).catch(res => {
                console.log(res)
            })
```

I would really appreciate the help on this one.

Comment: What version of react-native and axios you are on?

Comment: @VishalRajole I don't think that's the case... but `~0.62.2`

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28551 see if this thread helps

Comment: I think this thread can be helpful:
https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/973#issuecomment-437221047

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a problem with react-native. The bug is now patched (the new version 0.63.3)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that it's an axios issue.

If you're using an image picker or camera make sure you check the documentation as the path to the file selected differs between android and iOS.

Make sure you change the path of the item based on platform.OS === 'android'.
It should be clearly described in the docs of whatever you're using.

Comment: Not quite the answer. I'm using the form in other parts of my app and it works perfectly